# Why echo command does not need "-e" option when escaping "$" character with a backslash

Tags: bash, shell, quoting, echo

This is regarding bash builtin `echo`. Per Bash documentation the `-e` option enables interpretation of backslash escapes.
If I execute    `echo "Total Amount \$500"`, I see the expected output   `Total Amount $500`. Here I am able to use backslash to esacpe the "$" character without using the    `-e` option. But to escape a new line or tab charcater I am required to have    `-e` option in the 
   `echo` command like this-    `echo -e "Total Amount: \n \$500"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two steps of string transformation.

1. First bash parses the command line `echo -e "Total Amount: \n \$500"` and determines that it needs to invoke a command called `echo` with two arguments. The first argument is `-e`. The second argument is the result of expanding the double-quoted literal `"Total Amount: \n \$500"`. Given the rules for double-quoted strings¹, `\$` turns into `$` and `\n` stays `\n`, so the second argument that is passed to the `echo` command is `Total Amount: \n $500`.
2. The echo command, in `-e` mode, replaces some sequences beginning with backslash into a single character, e.g. it replaces `\n` by a newline character.

Note that “escaping” means two different things in your question. In the first step, the backslash in `\$` “escapes” the `$` in the sense that the `$` character escapes special processing and remains intact. In the second step, the backslash in `\n` “escapes” the normal processing to apply some special processing to the `n` which leads to a newline character.

¹  <sub>Backslash followed by one of `` "$\` `` becomes just the second character; backslash followed by anything else stays.</sub> 
²  <sub>Backslash followed by some lowercase letters becomes a control character; backslash followed by digits becomes the character with that code point in octal; backslash followed by one of `xuU` and some hexadecimal digits does the same with hexa; backslash followed by anything else becomes just the second character.</sub>

Answer (score 3):

The bash manual says the following regarding `echo` when used with the `-e` switch:

> If the -e option is given, interpretation of the following backslash-escaped characters is enabled.

It specifies "**the following** backslash-escaped characters" and then lists them:

```
\a
alert (bell)

\b
backspace

\c
suppress further output

\e
\E
escape

\f
form feed

\n
new line

\r
carriage return

\t
horizontal tab

\v
vertical tab

\\
backslash

\0nnn
the eight-bit character whose value is the octal value nnn (zero to three octal digits)

\xHH
the eight-bit character whose value is the hexadecimal value HH (one or two hex digits)

\uHHHH
the Unicode (ISO/IEC 10646) character whose value is the hexadecimal value HHHH (one to four hex digits)

\UHHHHHHHH
the Unicode (ISO/IEC 10646) character whose value is the hexadecimal value HHHHHHHH (one to eight hex digits)
```

This can be confusing because these are really more of an `escape sequence` than an `escape character` the `escape character` (`\`).

**Escape Sequence**

> An escape sequence is a sequence of characters that does not represent itself when used inside a character or string literal, but is translated into another character or a sequence of characters that may be difficult or impossible to represent directly.

**Escape Character**

> In computing and telecommunication, an escape character is a character which invokes an alternative interpretation on subsequent characters in a character sequence. An escape character is a particular case of metacharacters. Generally, the judgment of whether something is an escape character or not depends on context.

The `-e` option has very little to do with the escape character but allows it to be used in combination with the above `sequences` in order to have them interpreted with special meaning.

Comment: True, but this doesn't answer the question. What happens with `$`?

Comment: It's escaped normally. Op was confused about what the manual meant by `enables interpretation of backslash escapes` not about what the escape character does.  Also there is no question...

Comment: I think I understand now. The escape for the $ character was for bash, not echo command.

Comment: @RaviKumar, I've updated my question again.

Comment: FYI:  The question **IS NOT** "What happens with `$`?".  The question **IS** "Why does this escape work?"  And therefore I have in fact answered it.

Comment: I thought my question was clear. I want to know why echo does not need -e option for $ character while it needs the -e option for new line and few other characters.

Comment: @RaviKumar, your question is far from clear.  Have I answered it though?

Comment: And I am thinking it is not echo but the bash that is interpreting the $ character before it is passed to echo. For bash to interpret $ character it needed to be escaped with a backspace. Am I right ?

Comment: It's best to edit your question rather than leave comments like this.  I believe I understand you fine but the way you are wording your questions is leading to a great deal of confusion.  For example when you are using a word like `interpret` it would be best for you to also define what you mean.  I believe you are asking for two completely opposite things.

Comment: @RaviKumar Yes, that's it. `\$` protects `$` for bash so that it passes `$` to echo, `\n` tells echo to put a newline instead.

Comment: @jesse_b  I will be careful next time in  making sure my question is clear.  Your answer helped me understand what is actually happening. Thanks Gilles for confirming!